# 2 left alignments under cases

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, cases

I would like to align something under `cases` as follows:

```
value1                    if condition
value2  line1ofvalue2...  otherwise
        line2ofvalue2..
        line3ofvalue2.
```

First, there are only 2 conditions (each one for one value), so I want `if condition` and `otherwise` are left adjusted. Then as my `value2` is a long, I need to split it into 3 lines, so I want these 3 lines to be left adjusted.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `array` environment provides a very similar layout and typesetting to the [`amsmath` package](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) `cases` environment. In fact, `amsmath` defines `cases` exactly as an `array` with some stretch (an `\arraystretch` of `1.2`) and a specific column alignment (`@{}ll@{}`). Consider the following minimal example displaying the two different styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent Original \texttt{cases} example:
\[
X=%
  \begin{cases}
    0& \text{if $r-j$ is odd},\\
    r!\,(-1)^{(r-j)/2}& \text{if $r-j$ is even}.
  \end{cases}
\]

\noindent Using the \texttt{array} environment:
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
X=\left\{%
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    0& \text{if $r-j$ is odd},\\
    r!\,(-1)^{(r-j)/2}& \text{if $r-j$ is even}.
  \end{array}
  \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Array vs cases]

Therefore, using the `array` environment, one could attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent Requested environment using \texttt{array}:
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
X=\left\{%
  \begin{array}{@{}lll@{}}
    0& & \text{if $r-j$ is odd},\\
    k& +7& \text{if $r-j$ is even}. \\
    & +1+2i& \\
    & \binom{3}{n}
  \end{array}
  \right.
\]
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[image: Array environment similar to cases (with 3 columns)]

The gap between the first two `l`eft-aligned columns can also be adjusted (using `@{}l@{}ll@{}`, say) if needed. The advantage of this approach is flexibility in terms of the `array` environment, while still retaining the visual equivalence with the `cases` environment; that is, a user-defined `cases` environment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, what is the use of `%` in the `\left\{%`?

Comment: I almost use it out of habit, but it's best to read the short and long answer to this here: [What is the use of percent signs at the end of lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extension of the `amsmath` `cases` environment. There's a new optional argument for customizing the `cases` columns. Without argument, it work like the original `cases`.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\env@cases[1][@{}l@{\quad}l@{}]{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

The original definition in `amsmath.sty` contains `@{}l@{\quad}l@{}`, which we replaced by `#1`. Now you can use all features of `array` column specifications.

Complete example with usage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\env@cases[1][@{}l@{\quad}l@{}]{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{cases}
  value1 & if condition \\
  value2 & otherwise
\end{cases}
\]
\[
\begin{cases}[@{}lp{3cm}l@{}]
  value1 & & if condition \\
  value2 & line1ofvalue2 \newline
           line2ofvalue2 \newline
           line3ofvalue2          & otherwise
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Phantom}{\phantom{value2}}%
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
value1& condition1 \\
value2 \text{ line1ofvalue2}& condition2\\
\Phantom \text{ line2ofvalue2}\\
\Phantom \text{ line3ofvalue2}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```